# restangular multiple promise jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I try to test if my array (storage) got one more item with Jasmine. I have multiple promise chain but i can't enter in the first, nothing happen into the promise (.then).

This is my test :

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($state, $controller, $rootScope, $q) {
    state = $state.get('app.provision_requests_create');
    ctrl = $controller('ProvisionRequestsCreateCtrl', {
      $scope: $rootScope.$new(),
      provider: {
        data: {
          priceStorage: function () {
            return $q(function (resolve) {
              resolve({ data: [] });
            });
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }));

  describe("should test add Volume", function() {
    it('should remove volume properly ', function () {

      ctrl.createVolume(volume);
      ctrl.provider.priceStorage().then(function(){
        console.log('ok');
      });

    });
```

This is my function :

```
_this.provider = provider.data;
_this.instance.additional_values.storage = [];

_this.createVolume = function (volume) {
    var newvol = angular.copy(volume);

    //reset input and select
    angular.copy({},volume);

    return _this.provider.priceStorage(newvol.kind).then(function (resp) {
      ...
      return _this.provider.priceSnapshot();
    })
    .then(function (resp) {
      _this.instance.additional_values.storage.push(newvol);
    });
  };
```

When I console.log ctrl.provider.priceStorage() I have this

> d{$$state: Object{status: 1, value: Object{data: ...}}}

When I console.log ctrl.createVolume(), I have this

> d{$$state: Object{status: 0}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ctrl.provider.priceStorage()` is a promise.

Promises are tested in this fashion:

```
  ctrl.provider.priceStorage().then(function (result) {
    expect(result).toEqual(...);
  });
  $rootScope.$digest();
```

Use [Jasmine Promise matchers](https://github.com/bvaughn/jasmine-promise-matchers) to flatten promise chains in specs.

Comment: thanks but i know that , the problem is nothing happen in my promise, even when i write whatever like this expect(result).toEqual('okokok'); I have no result, no error, nothing ...

Comment: @user3703539 Use $rootScope.$digest() to trigger $q chains in specs.